# How to compare a CSS value numerically?

Tags: cypress

I want to test if the text in all selected elements are bold. In a very narrow sense, a text with [font-weight 700 is bold](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#syntax). So this seems to work as a test:

```
cy.get('.foo').should('have.css', 'font-weight', '700');
```

But IMO very bold is still bold. Thus I would like to test if font-weight is 700 or greater. However, this does not work:

```
cy.get('.foo').should('have.css', 'font-weight').and('be.gte', 700);
```

The error says “expected '700' to be a number or a date”.

Any idea how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font-weight is returned as a string - you can see this in your first code snippet, where you are checking that the font-weight is equal to `'700'` and not `700`.

So, we simply have to parse the [string into a number](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/9.6.0/recipes/parse-numbers.html#parseint)!

```js
cy.get('.foo')
  .should('have.css', 'font-weight') // yields the font-weight, as a string
  .then(parseInt) // parses the strings
  .and('be.gte', 700);
// Alternative if this answer gives you errors in your IDE
cy.get('.foo')
  .should('have.css', 'font-weight') // yields the font-weight, as a string
  .then((fontWeight) => +fontWeight) // parses the strings
  .and('be.gte', 700);
```

If that seems cumbersome to repeat over and over, you could make a Cypress custom command

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('validateBold', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
return 
  cy.wrap(subject)
    .should('have.css', 'font-weight')
    .then((fontWeight) => +fontWeight)
    .and('be.gte', 700);
});
```